# Abodu Random number

Tags: javascript

I create this code it work but I have two problem how to convert this number to string to use, and I want random date like: 20190328

how to random number return 02 number like this

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

function test() {
var year = getRndInteger(4, 9); 
var month = getRndInteger(01, 12);
 var day = getRndInteger(01, 28); 
  var date = year.toString() .. month.toString() .. day.toString()
  var response = ( "20" .. date..");


  };
```

output:
Unterminated string literal.

Comment: Unterminated string literal is because in the line `ar response = ( "20" .. date..");` The double quote is incorrectly closed/opened. As you can see the last quote is never closed

Comment: `var response = ( "20" .. date..");` is a syntax error. You have an extra double quote (`"`) at the end of your string.

Comment: Apart form the error message, in JS there's no number format like `02`.

Comment: This code has so many errors that the best I can recommend is to actually **run** the code and check the console, fixing line by line every issue.

Comment: `this code is work` ... yet `output: Unterminated string literal.` - how is this "working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected All the Issues, try

You can use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) for appending a single digit number with 0.

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function test() {
 var year = `201${getRndInteger(4, 9)}`;
 var month = getRndInteger(1, 12).toString().padStart(2, 0);
 var day = getRndInteger(1, 28).toString().padStart(2, 0);
 var date = year + month + day
 return date;
};

console.log(test())
```

In Old fasioned way

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function test() {
 var year = `201${getRndInteger(4, 9)}`;
 var month = getRndInteger(1, 12).toString();
 month = month.length === 2 ? month : 0 + month 
 var day = getRndInteger(1, 28).toString();
 day = day.length === 2 ? day : 0 + day
 var date = year + month + day
 return date;
};

console.log(test())
```

Comment: this is basically a code only answer :p you haven't *taught* the OP a thing, just given him code that he probably won't understand what you did different :p

Comment: There are already a lot of comments to tell what's wrong, if OP has an issue and cant Understand he can ask, however adding links for padStart, That's the only thing new to be added. :)

Comment: which line @aqballahor (guessing 6, and that you use an OLD nodejs, or *shudder* Internet Exploder browser)

Comment: @AZ_ that may be true, but an answer should stand alone without comments :p comments are for nit-pickers like me :p

Comment: line 5 and the function padStart undefined

Comment: so, am I right, @aqballahor - Internet Exploder browser? or Node 0.11 or something?

Comment: guessed it, @aqballahor will add the code to do it in old fashioned way

Comment: [Polyfill for padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Polyfill) ... and `\`\`` ... you'll have to read about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) too

Comment: I just working on google-script i don't know if it have old version :(

Comment: @aqballahor try another snippet

Comment: @JaromandaX needed to be first one then you can update your answer as many times as you want, but thanks :P

Comment: `needed to be first one` - oh dear, really? :D

Comment: Thx AZ_ you are the best!